# mysql, php calculate mean per month with multiple userid's

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me crazy, I cant seam to manage this without massive amount of code, this is my sql table:

```
userid    date        orderValue
2       2012-01-01      2000
1       2012-01-01      3000
1       2012-01-01      5000
1       2012-01-02      5000
2       2012-01-02      8000
2       2012-01-02      8000
```

For each month I need to get the mean value per user from the first date ever intill the current month.

The output I'am looking for is something along the line of
$orderArray[$month][$userid]['mean']

I don't relay need the code, jut need to get my mind out the current thoughts that man stuck on. How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  `userid`,
  DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%m') AS `month`,
  AVG(`orderValue`) AS `mean`
FROM
  `orderTable`
GROUP BY
  `userid`,
  `month`
```

Note that I'm using `DATE_FORMAT` instead of `MONTH`. If you don't do this, January 2012 and January 2013 would effectively be merged, which I guess is not what you want.

You'll have to create the desired result array yourself in PHP by iterating over the SQL result set and putting each mean value in the appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks you Bart! It was to long ago i used SQL, forgot that you could do multiple 'group by', make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
    Select
    userid,
    SUM(ordervalue)/count(*) as mean

    from table 
    group by 

   userid
```

Comment: ...from the first day ever... I think the OP wants the mean of everything up to the current month, per month (cumulative is the word I think?).

Comment: Yes, I need the mean of the cumulative sum per user. Not the mean of that single month.

Comment: @Robin : Pleasec check the query now